# Bootable file explorer like Geekbox

Tags: file-management

Is there any Bootable file explorer like Geekbox?

Answer (score 1):

Neither [Geekbox](http://www.geekbox.net/), [Geekbox](http://www.geekboxcomputers.com/), [Geekbox](http://popey.com/blog/2010/02/18/geekbox/), nor [Geekbox](http://www.bigbadtoystore.com/bbts/menu.aspx?menu=1958) is a file explorer.  [Geexbox](http://geexbox.org/) isn't either, but at least it's bootable.

If you just need to boot a computer and view the filesystem, grab any Linux [live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download) and boot to it.  If you need more requirements, you'll need to state what they are to get a useful answer.